# Azure Pipeline - build and gen swagger doc

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, azure-pipelines, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.examples

My project is an AspNet Core 2.2 Api, I am building it in Azure Pipelines (classic) I want to generate the swagger document during an azure pipeline build - for this I am using [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli and the documents in Retrieve Swagger Directly from a Startup Assembly](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcorecli)

1. I have a [Use .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) task set to 2.2 at the beginning of the job
2. I have installed the tools using *.NET Core task* with *custom* tool command with arguments `install swashbuckle.aspnetcore.cli --version 5.0.0-rc4 --global`, this seemed to work; If I run this task again it fails with message that tool is already installed.
3. Then in my CI Build, I added a .NET Core task with settings

   - command to Custom
   - Path to Project(s) to *the path csproj file*
   - Custom command to `swagger`
   - Arguments to `tofile --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/swagger.json $($(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)_Dxxxxx.Api.dll v1`

I'm getting this error `No executable found matching command "dotnet-swagger"`

Help!
[image]

Comment: Try to add in your `.csproj` this: `<ItemGroup> <DotNetCliToolRefernce Include-Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli" Version="5.0.0" /> </ItemGroup>`

Comment: Have you tried in your local vs? This error seems has no relation to Azure DevOps, please follow https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcorecli and do this in local vs see if you can reproduce the problem. Most likely the cli tool is not installed correctly or there's a version conflict between this tool and your core sdk.

Comment: I have not found a specific resolution to the issue - I have added the `DotNetCliToolRefernce` per @ShaykiAbramczyk comments.

However I worked around it by adding a Command Line Task and executed the swagger.exe directly from this task

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using the JAR maintained by the Swagger Codegen team.

I used the public microsoft `speech-to-text-api-v3` API but feel free to change it.

```
trigger:
  - master

variables:
  jar_version: 3.0.29


- job: swagger_client
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
    displayName: 'Set-up Java'
  - script: |
      java -version
      wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/codegen/v3/swagger-codegen-cli/$(jar_version)/swagger-codegen-cli-$(jar_version).jar -O swagger-codegen-cli.jar
      java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate \
        -i https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/export\?DocumentFormat\=Swagger\&ApiName\=Speech%20to%20Text%20API%20v3.0 \
        -l python \
        -o lib/python-client
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    inputs:
      patterns: 'python-client/**'
      path: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/lib/python-client
```